# How to replace Wildcard url in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to replace all URLs that start with `https://oneweburl.com/cm` with `https://anotherwebsite.com`

i.e. URLs such as

```
https://oneweburl.com/cm/9304/434
https://oneweburl.com/cm/849/495/34
https://oneweburl.com/cm/2994/234/54
```

will be replaced with only `https://anotherwebsite.com`. So far I have tried

```
update wp_posts 
set post_content = 
    replace(post_content, 'https://oneweburl.com/cm/%', 'https://anotherwebsite.com');
```

Apparently that didn't work. Any idea the SQL to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: It is  MySQL database

Answer (score 2):

For the most part, you should be able to do:

```
update wp_posts
    set post_content = replace(post_content, 'https://oneweburl.com/cm/', 'https://anotherwebsite.com/')
    where post_content like 'https://oneweburl.com/cm/%';
```

This should work in any database.

The one issue is if `post_content` could have multiple URLs in the string.  This will replace all matches to the specified string.  If that is an issue, you can do string manipulations to do the right thing.  Alas, those tend to depend on the specific database.

Comment: "http%oneweburl.com/cm/%" will handle the differences (https, http, www).